# How/Possible to do Key-based Pagination in Mysql Which has a order by cluase with a colum of type varchar(150)

Tags: mysql, optimization, pagination, query-optimization

I have to query ~500k records in a column and curently it takes about ~15s to finish the entire operation. Currently I am using pagination like this

```sql
SELECT 
      columnA,
      columnB,
      columnC,
      columnD,
      name
    
FROM
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON
    ${condition1}
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON
    ${condition2}
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON
    ${condition3}
WHERE
${WhereConditions}
-- would like to have a key based pagination in where
GROUP BY c.id_number
HAVING ${aggregateCondition}
ORDER BY
    name ASC
LIMIT 20 , 20
```

But my current implementation yeilds no difference in fetching paginated result and all results

So I stumbled upon key-based pagination or seeking-pagination, but all the examples I sqw was based on some key which is an integer or DateTime.
So I was wondering if it's possible to do something like key-based pagination on varchar?

Below image is the Explain part of the query[image]

Comment: Have you just tried it? There is absolutely no difference between using varchar or integer or date for pagination. (It might get a little more complicated if your varchar gets too long to being indexes (e.g. around 3k bytes). Nevertheless, pagination in the where-condition doesn't seem to be the right place for it, as you usually paginate on the resultset (e.g. here after grouping), although it could work, depending on your columns. Also check if name is functionally dependent on c.id_number (e.g. if one c.id_number can have 2 names or columnA to D), otherwise, your query is undeterministic.

Answer (score 1):

You hope to paginate a result set with `ORDER BY name LIMIT offset, 20`. And, of course you've discovered that `LIMIT large_offset, 20` is painfully slow.

So you're looking for a way to do `WHERE ... name > ?previous_page_name ... ORDER BY name LIMIT 20` to avoid large offsets. That's generally good for efficiency if you can exploit an index.

But here's the problem you face: `name` values *probably are not unique*. What if you have 22 `Francis` names, then 26  `Jones`, then 13 `Smith`? Your first page will be fine, but your second page won't. It will skip the last two `Francis` rows and show 20 `Jones` rows.

Index-based pagination really requires ordering by an indexed unique value.

And of course any reliable pagination requires stable ordering: with duplicate `name` values, `ORDER BY name` doesn't always return the rows in the same order.

In many apps using pagination, there's an underlying assumption that the user will look at one, two, or three pages, and then give up and try a different way of finding the data. The assumption says the user won't paginate all the way through. This means the performance problem with later pages doesn't matter.

So duplicated data is your problem. To give a more detailed suggestion about how to fix it requires more understanding of your data than you have given in your question.

Comment: Yes there can be duplicate names and if duplicate we have to sort by timestamp of the person added. And the unique Identifier happens to be binary(16) rather than autoincrement unique Id. I am not sure How to fix it better.

Comment: You need some column or combination of columns both sequential and unique. I suspect your BINARY column contains a UUID; those aren't sequential.